# Images and GIFs not displaying in GitHub anywhere

Tags: github, networking, repository, github-pages

Images and gifs file formats are not loaded into any repository on my local network and any browser(google chrome, Firefox, opera, etc.).

Image For Reference:

[image: Image For Reference]

I have Jio's 5G network with up to 50MBPS speed, and the network is never slowing down.

My network speed:

[image: my network speed]

Github website inspect this error show:

[image: github website inspect this error show]

I have tried opening the page in google's incognito mode, but it doesn't work.

If I use a VPN in my network, it works fine. But loading very slow.